# Why does a finite operator norm of a linear transformation imply uniform continuity.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I am following *Real Mathematical Analysis* by Pugh.

I do not understand this simple proof

[image]

which gives (b).

But why is $|Tv - Tv'| \le ||T|||v-v'|$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: The claim is trivial when $v=v^\prime$. Otherwise, $$\frac{\left|Tv-Tv^{\prime}\right|}{\left|v-v^{\prime}\right|}=\frac{\left|T\left(v-v^{\prime}\right)\right|}{\left|v-v^{\prime}\right|}\leq\sup_{x\neq0}\frac{\left|Tx\right|}{\left|x\right|}=\ldots$$

Comment: Took me a while to see it even if the hint is really obvious :(, but thanks a bunch. Could you even tell me why this implies uniform continuity?

Comment: I'll give a less obvious hint this time. $T$ is uniformly continuous if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such  that for every $v,v^\prime$ with $|v-v^\prime|<\delta$, $|Tv-Tv^\prime|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Take $\delta =  \epsilon / ||T||$ then $|v- v'| < \delta  \implies  |Tv-Tv^\prime|<\epsilon ||T|| /  ||T||$ , correct? By the way I was disappointed in the time I took to see your previous hint not the by the quality of the hint. Thanks again :) .

Comment: Correct. Don't be disappointed. Just keep at it.